# "not all code paths return a value" even when code returns for all inputs

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write code that returns whether or not a given integer is or is not divisible evenly by 1 to 20, but i keep receiving

> error CS0161: 'ProblemFive.isTwenty(int)': not all code paths return a value"

Here is my code:

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    {
        if(num % j != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(num % j == 0 && num == 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The fact you see that method always returns something does not mean compiler can see it.

**Compiler does only simple checks and in your example logic is too complicated for compiler to see that.**

It's not even smart enough to allow that kind of method:

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

***Solution***

Add another `return` at the end of the method:

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    {
        if(num % j != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(num % j == 0 && num == 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But in this case you can just make your `for` loop a little different and delete `else if` part:

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    {
        if(num % j != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the response from these code samples to `isTwenty(0)` ?

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn That's not the point of the question. I don't think the code does what OP wants it to. I'm just showing how to get rid of error.

Comment: @MarcinJarszek Fair enough.

Comment: +1. One can also convert to well-know infinite loop with `while(true)` or `for(...;true;...)` (posted sample as answer too).

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a value from the method also after the loop.

In fact, your `else if` condition is the same as if you just finished the iterations through the loop, so it's simpler just to do this:

```
public static bool isDivisibleByAllLessThanOrEqualToTwenty(int num) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
        if(num % j != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `if` and an `else if` but no `else`. It is not guaranteed that either one of the `if` or `else if` will always be evaluated.

Comment: Its not `if/else if`, The compiler can't even determine whether control would go inside the `for` loop, regardless of conditions.

Comment: Very interesting. I looked at that and figured since the loop counter does not use a variable, the compiler would be able to determine whether the loop was entered at all or not. If that isn't the case, how does the compiler unroll loops?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider what happens if neither of the two conditions are met for all iterations of `j`.

**Edit**: A more efficient way of determining whether a number is exactly divisible by all numbers in a fixed range is to take the least common multiple (LCM) of your range, and simply check whether the said number is divisible by the LCM.

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
                 // compile-time computation
    const int lcm = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19;        
    return num % lcm == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or just a little one-liner (useless of course), to avoid forgetting a return

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, 20).All(x => num % x == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered why in terms of code, but perhaps an example will help?
What is the response from your code for the following inputs?

```
isTwenty(0);

isTwenty(21);

isTwenty(-1);
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? If you have a question to the OP, ask in the comments. That's what comments are good for ;)

Comment: Yes, It's an answer, the issue is that one or more of the conditions may not be met (in the `for` loop or the `if` conditionals). 
"If you have questions for the poster, ask in the comments," you don't have to vote down too.

Comment: It is an answer? If that is an answer, then what is a question?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you want to keep your logic - replace `for` with well-known infinite loop since *you* know that it will always exit. Compiler will understand that and let you keep `return` just inside if:

```
public static bool isTwenty(int num)
{
    for(int j = 1; true; j++)
    {
        if(num % j != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(num % j == 0 && num == 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if `while` works better:

```
    var j = 1;
    while(true) 
    {
        if (...){...}
        j++;

    }
```